# Electron NPM ERR! Missing Script: Start

Tags: node.js, electron

I know this has been asked before, but that question did not help me at all! So I am trying to make an Electron app using its [tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#create-a-basic-application), and whenever I try and run my code, this error pops up:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
"name": "my-electron-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron ."
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for those of you who had a similar problem, try using a different shell! I was using WSL and when I tried Windows command prompt everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I can't think of many reasons why this is happening. I have a few ideas that may help.

1. Check you are in the correct folder to run the command
2. Attempt `npm run start` instead

If neither of these work, there may be something else that is missing